# Has anyone succesfully loaded a YAML file using SnakeYAML from a local Maven repo?

Tags: java, maven-2, yaml, snakeyaml

If I reference the [SnakeYAML](http://trac-hg.assembla.com/snakeyaml/wiki) jar directly from a test program (see bottom), everything works. If I'm inside my Maven-created project, I get the following output from my unit tests:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.LinkedList.push(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.addIndent(ScannerImpl.java:482)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchBlockEntry(ScannerImpl.java:653)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:268)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:178)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseImplicitDocumentStart.produce(ParserImpl.java:213)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:172)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:143)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:163)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getSingleNode(Composer.java:66)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:60)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Loader.load(Loader.java:35)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:134)
```

Since Maven couldn't find SnakeYAML in the central repos, I manually installed it into my local repo. In case it matters, I'm on a Mac using SnakeYAML 0.9, and Maven 2.0.9.

**Sample YAML File**

```
- 
    accountCode: foo
    accountId: 1
    email: foo@bar.com
    userId: 1
```

**Working Test Program**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;

/**
 * Testing SnakeYAML.
 *
 * @author Hank Gay
 */
public final class Foo {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        Reader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new FileReader("/tmp/foo.yaml");
            System.out.println(yaml.load(reader));
        } catch (final FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.err.println("We had a problem reading the YAML from the file because we couldn't find the file." + fnfe);
        } finally {
            if (null != reader) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException ioe) {
                    System.err.println("We got the following exception trying to clean up the reader: " + ioe);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a JDK version issue: `LinkedList#push` was [introduced in Java 6](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#push(E)).

Try setting `JAVA_HOME` to the correct version before running Maven.

Comment: Thanks. `java -version` revealed 1.6, but `mvn -version` revealed I had the wrong JDK referened in $JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 2):

fixed in release 1.0rc1

All Java 6 dependencies are removed from SnakeYAML.

Comment: Is there some documentation on which <repository> I need to add to my POM to get SnakeYAML to download? I wound up just installing the JAR manually.

Comment: There is no remote repository yet. Once SnnkeYAML reaches 1.0 it will be uploaded somewhere.

Comment: SnakeYAML 1.0 is released. The remote MAven 2 repository can be found here:
http://trac-hg.assembla.com/snakeyaml